# Davfs, write permissions for any user

Tags: linux, webdav, davfs2

I have Windows with VirtualBox where Ubuntu is running. In Ubuntu I have davfs2 server and the mount point for example like /home/user1/webdav_folder/.

I'm able to see webdav_folder from host Windows system, but I can't change any file, there is no write permission in this case. How can I fix it?